# NoSuchMethodError while using setCustomInsertionActionModeCallback for API<23

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am using Nexus 6 (API 22) . I want to add some more options when user long press on Edittext. Normally when we long press on Edittext, paste popup menu will appear and I want to add some more features in addtion to paste menu.

Android documentation says, when we implement setCustomInsertionActionModeCallback we can override the behaviour but in my case it is not working. But in Nexus 6P (API 23) it is working fine.Any help will be appreciated.

This is the error I've got while implementing setCustomInsertionActionModeCallback

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setCustomInsertionActionModeCallback(Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;)V in class L/view/WriterEditText; or its super classes (declaration of 'view.WriterEditText' appears in /data/app/-1/base.apk)
         at .EditorViewManager.createEditText(EditorViewManager.java:79)
         at render.EditorViewManager.createViewAtIndex(EditorViewManager.java:207)
         at render.Renderer.renderContent1(Renderer.java:158)
         at render.Renderer.renderContent(Renderer.java:135)
         at .render.Renderer.reloadDocument(Renderer.java:704)
         at EditorActivity.onCreate(EditorActivity.java:89)
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That method was added in API Level 23. You cannot use it on older devices. You are welcome to wrap your call in a `Build` version check:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
  // call that method
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any way to access paste popup menu that shows when we long press on edittext?

Comment: @vijay: I have not looked into this, sorry.

Comment: Do you know any alternative for this action on API Level 22?

Comment: @user2751809: No, but I have not gone looking for one, either.